# How to resolve this Query builder error

Tags: runtime-error, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am new to CRM 365. I were creating many cases since last 2 days and tried editing the phone to case business process flow. Since then whether I create a new case or else I try to view any case I get a Query builder error. And the downloaded text file specifies this message "'Incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'IncidentResolution_LinkControl'."

Context is dynamics CRM 365. Please help anyone?

Text file below:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #3BA08A21Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>3ce940dd-a4a8-4e61-a4da-051a35f5ab9e</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #3BA08A21</Message>
  <Timestamp>2016-12-22T06:10:30.7389644Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>3ce940dd-a4a8-4e61-a4da-051a35f5ab9e</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147217149</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>'Incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'IncidentResolution_LinkControl'.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2016-12-22T06:10:30.7389644Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Momd, have you done customization on either of entities? may be javascript? give us something like you can attach the text file here.

Comment: This was phone to case business process flow. So it included details of a account and attached contacts.  I did these customization:   First I tried editing the stage of process flow by adding new steps, conditions. The I created a new entity(Store, which I have deleted now ). But the store entity didn't have any relation with case I guess.

Comment: Check the edits in the post @Nachiket.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, if you have Resolve step in the Business Process Flow, remove it and try again.

Comment: @Nachiket see i have attached the screenshot of current business process flow. You want me to remove the last stage? That is Resolve stage?  Or the step under that stage?

Comment: Yes remove the step and save it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131223/discussion-between-nachiket-and-mohd-tahir).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the last step and replacing it by another step. (not resolve case) . But rather I added **CSAT survey** step.